# pdfbox textbox value not setting

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to fill in PDF forms that we've been given by a third party.

I'm having a problem with only 1 of the forms, this code works for 21 others.

I know the `valueToSet` has value and is correct, and within the `setField` method, the `getField` method does return a value, so I know the field name is correct too.  Plus, this code works fine with many other forms. None of the fields are populating (this particular template only has text boxes anyway).

What am I missing?  Is there something on this specific form I should be looking for?

`setField(formFieldName, valueToSet);`

```
public static void setField(String name, String value ) throws IOException {
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    PDField field = acroForm.getField( name );
    if (field instanceof PDCheckBox){
        String onValue = ((PDCheckBox) field).getOnValue();
        String offValue = "Off";
        if(value.equals("Yes")){
            field.setValue(onValue);
        }
        else{
            field.setValue(offValue);
        }
    }
    else{
        field.setValue(value);          
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [this](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/SetField.java?view=markup). I don't however see any errors in your code - it should set a field.

Comment: This definitely has to do with security on the document.  In a roundabout way I took all the security settings off of the document we were given and the code above worked as it should have.

Comment: Please mention what PDFBox version you are using. If possible, share the document. And explain what you did to "took all the security settings off".